# Can someone explain { } container in c++

Tags: c++, stl, set, containers, min

Can someone explain the {} in c++.
it is used with all containers.
example.

I generally use it to make a container like set or vector empty.

I have confusion in using the min/ max function for multiple values with it.

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
int a = min(v) // doesn't work.
int b = min({1,2,3,4,5}) // works and gives accurate answer.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `std::min` and `std::max` have an overload taking `std::initializer_list`, which could be constructed from braced-init-list like `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

`min(v)` doesn't work because there's no overload taking `std::vector`.

Since C++11 STL containers like `std::vector` and `std::list` could be [list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) from braced-init-list too; when being initialized from empty one (i.e. `{}`) they would be [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) by default constructor. For non-empty braced-init-list they would be initialized by the overloaded constructor taking `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 6):

There's an overload of [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) that takes an [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). And it's this overload that is used for

```
int b = min({1,2,3,4,5});
```

To get the minimum element of a generic iterable container you need to use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
int a = std::min_element(begin(v), end(v));
```

For max values use `std::max` or `std::max_element`, as applicable.

Comment: Does C++20 Ranges enhance this kind of operation?  (I'm still on C++14, so I'm way behind the latest improvements.)

Comment: @Eljay I haven't had the time to check out ranges yet (not even the old ranges-v3 library it's mostly based on) so I don't really know. But I would guess it would.